# How to delay image display with external javascript

Tags: javascript, image, timer, delay

I'm do it on external script :

```
var t=setTimeout(function(){document.write('<img src="/image.jpg" width="100" height="100" />')},10000)
```

then on main page :

```
<script type='text/javascript src='external.js' />
```

but after 10s main page just display full image.jpg, 
how to display the image on main page ?
thank's

Answer (score 1):

If you call `document.write` after the page load it will content of the page. Instead of using `document.write` you can have the image in the page as normal but hidden (use css) and then 10 seconds after the page loads show it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a document.write after the page render, the current page will be overwritten by the contents specified in the document.write("").

If the intention is to show an image on a time out, you could change the visibility of a pre-existing image after the timeout, or you could dynamically create a new image element using document.createElement.

Comment: Thank's. can you tell me sample that using document.createElement for image, sory i'm stupid?